# TYPO3: f:link.action view helper ignores controller property

Tags: typo3, fluid

Using the following template code, the `controller` property gets ignored:

```
<f:link.action
        pageUid="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.nav.pid.registration')}"
        controller="StandardRegistration"
        action="oneClickRegistration"
        additionalParams="{tx_extension_standardregistration: '{occurrenceId: conductingEvent.id}'}">
    <f:translate key="registration.label.register"/>
</f:link.action>
```

Instead of calling the action `oneClickRegistration`, the page gets processed as if no controller property has been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the property `additionalParams`, I had to use `arguments`:

```
<f:link.action
        pageUid="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.nav.pid.registration')}"
        controller="StandardRegistration"
        action="oneClickRegistration"
        arguments="{occurrenceId: conductingEvent.id}">
    <f:translate key="registration.label.register"/>
</f:link.action>
```

The [documentaiton for the additionalParams property](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Link/Action.html#additionalparams) says:

> Additional query parameters that won't be prefixed like $arguments (overrule $arguments).

So it seems not only `arguments` gets overruled, but also the property `controller`.

Comment: You can control this using the various "queryString" related toggles on the ViewHelper. Same toggle appears on many others which support the "additionalParams" argument and creates links using typoLink.

Comment: @ClausDue I do not understand what you mean by "queryString" related toggles. Can you please add a link which explains it?

Comment: See https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Link/PageViewHelper.html arguments addQueryString, addQueryStringMethod, additionalParams, argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString.

Comment: The properties you listed do define, how the current query parameters are taken into the generated link.
But as far as I can see the link you sent does not contain any information, why the property `additionalParams` overrules the properties `controller` and `action`.

Comment: Well, `additionalParams` indicates that these get applied last and so, if it contains arguments that were already defined, the "additional" ones replace those. The short version: `controller` and others on `f:link.action` are shortcuts to setting those same parameters with prefixes in `additionalParams` and normally you only want to use the shortcuts (but using the other methods can allow for more detailed manipulation of the resulting URL). To get the full picture please read up on how typoLink works in TYPO3 ;)

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html does not help either to get an understanding. Do you have a link to an article which enlightns me?